# Give an example of integers k and b such that k| Φ(b) and yet no integer has order k (mod b).

Tags: number-theory

[image]

I was told to choose k=4 and b=8 so 4| Φ(8), but I don't understand why.

- 1^2 ≡ 1 (mod 8)
- 3^2 ≡ 1 (mod 8)
- 5^2 ≡ 1 (mod 8)
- 7^2 ≡ 1 (mod 8)

I understand that each has order 2 (mod 8), so it does not relate to order 4 (mod 8).

Comment: When proving $ a ^ {\phi(b)}\equiv 1 \pmod{b}$, that shows that the order of $a$ divides $\phi (b)$. It need not be equal to it for some $a$. While it is true for primes, so to look for counter examples we consider composite numbers. Another good candidate is $b = 6$.

Comment: the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) can be less than the Euler's totient function -- that's true for $8$, $12$, $15$, $16$ and other higher numbers

Comment: @CalvinLin what do you mean when you wrote, "it need not be equal to it for some a?"